# Code Igniter redirect() not working in IE9

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, authentication, session, redirect

I'm trying to login to my site with Facebook and it works in all browsers except for IE9!

My function gets all the way to 'redirect('home');' but then stops and stays on the current page. So all the session data gets set and the user is logged into Facebook, but they stay on the login page without being redirected.

Here is my code:

```
public function fb_login()
{
    if($this->fb_connect->user_id){
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('user_data');
        
        // Check if the user had previously logged in using facebook connect
        $fb_user = $this->fb_connect->user;
        $user_details = $this->Model->check_fb_user($fb_user);
        // This will then return their user details
        
        if($user_details['status'] == 0) redirect('account');
        
        $user_data['raw_details'] = $user_details;
        $user_data['fb_id'] = $this->fb_connect->user_id;
        $user_data['join_date'] = date( 'dS F, Y', strtotime($user_details['date_added']) );
        $user_data['location'] = $user_details['user_location'];
        $user_data['name'] = $user_details['user_fname'] . ' ' . $user_details['user_lname'];
        $user_data['display_name'] = $user_details['user_display_name'];
        $user_data['fb_dp'] = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_details['fb_id'].'/picture';
        
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_data',$user_data);
        
        if($this->session->userdata('referer')){
            $referer = $this->session->userdata('referer');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('referer');
            
            redirect($referer);
        }else{
            redirect('home');
        }
        
    }else{
                    error_log('148');
        redirect('account/login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure, add base_url()

> redirect(base_url().'account/login');

Answer (score 0):

From the CI docs at this URL, you might try the optional parameters.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

> The optional second parameter allows you to choose between the
>   "location" method (default) or the "refresh" method. Location is
>   faster, but on Windows servers it can sometimes be a problem.